# JUnit and Surefire Parallel Tests - ForkCount & ThreadCount

Tags: java, selenium, junit, parallel-processing, surefire

I'm running Selenium tests on the Selenium Grid using the Surefire Plugin to execute tests.
In terms of my test breakdown I have several classes, some of which have 1 test in there and some more than one test.

So on my Grid i have 30 chrome web drivers and I want to execute all tests within all classes in parallel.

I've read how to do this using the `parallel` parameter which i have set as:

```
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>${testSuite}</include>
                    </includes>
                    <parallel>all</parallel>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                    <perCoreThreadCount>false</perCoreThreadCount>
                    <threadCount>20</threadCount>
                    <browser>${browser_type}</browser>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

However this doesnt seem to fill all the Chrome web drivers I have available.

If i then use `forkCount`, like:

```
<forkCount>20</forkCount>
<reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
```

Then when the test execution first starts, all web drivers are filled however it quickly starts dropping and behaving one at a time.

So my questions:

- Is there a relationship between forkCount and threadCount
- Is there anything additional I need to do to really get this running in parallel?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using @NotThreadSafe  on your tests? Everything you need is here https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html

Comment: No - not using that @NotThreadSafe

Comment: selenium scripts are designed to run in parallel?  otherwise all the thread actions will happen in single chrome browser.

Comment: You are going to need to write a custom junit runner to allocate the tests to the different parallel threads correctly and clean up after yourself.  It doesn't work out of the box, it will appear to do so at first but the threads won't get reused.

Answer (score 4):

You have to provide explicit junit test provider:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <parallel>all</parallel>
        <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
        <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
        <includes>
            <include>${testSuite}</include>
        </includes>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <browser>${browser_type}</browser>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And you should use JUnit 4.7+ as older versions does not work with parallel testing correctly.

Also you can omit fork-related parameters if your tests do NOT affect JVM runtime (usually it's not the case).

Or migrate your tests to TestNG - it is more elegant framework and it works with parallel testing much better, then JUnit (imo).

Comment: surefire-junit47 is automatically selected if you use junit 4.8+ and are using a <groups> parameter in your configuration:  http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html#Using_JUnit_Categories

Comment: @Ardesco - true/false. true, because you are right. false, because OP does not use groups. however explicit declaration guarantees the correct test provider will be used.

Comment: Using dependecnies withing plugin made no difference. (I'm using jUnit 4.11)

Comment: As I wrote before - you should use JUnit 4.7+ as older versions does not work with parallel testing correctly (via surefire plugin). Consider to update JUnit 4.11 => 4.7.

Comment: Isnt 4.11 more recent that 4.7 ? (11 > 7 )?

Comment: @userMod2 Huh... Sometimes I'm being stupid. And you opened my eyes.

Answer (score 4):

There are so many configuration for running test in parallel.

According to the documentation:

**forkCount**

> The parameter `forkCount` defines the maximum number of JVM processes that Surefire will spawn concurrently to execute the tests. It supports the same syntax as `-T` in maven-core: if you terminate the value with a `C`, that value will be multiplied with the number of available CPU cores in your system. For example `forkCount=2.5C` on a Quad-Core system will result in forking up to ten concurrent JVM processes that execute tests.
>
> ...
>
> The default setting is `forkCount=1`/`reuseForks=true`, which means that Surefire creates one new JVM process to execute all tests in one maven module.

**threadCount**

> When using `reuseForks=true` and a `forkCount` value larger than one, test classes are handed over to the forked process one-by-one. Thus, `parallel=classes` would not change anything. However, you can use `parallel=methods`: classes are executed in `forkCount` concurrent processes, each of the processes can then use `threadCount` threads to execute the methods of one class in parallel.

As fair as I understand, `threadCount` is like a sub threading for each fork.

You can tweak these params to improve your test performance, for instance you can have:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
    <configuration>
         <includes>
              <include>${testSuite}</include>
         </includes>
         <parallel>all</parallel>
         <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
         <perCoreThreadCount>false</perCoreThreadCount>
         <forkCount>2.0C</forkCount>
         <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
         <threadCount>20</threadCount>
         <browser>${browser_type}</browser>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You can find more details in its site:

https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html

Comment: I've experimented with these however the issue I get is all my chrome drivers are not being filled even though I am throwing enough tests at it.

Comment: @userMod2 seems a problem with your test cases setup and not with the way you want to run them concurrently. For instance, you can remove all parallelism and check if your drivers are filled, if not then you have another problem. As far as I can tell, you may have a problem within your `@Before` or `@BeforeClass` annotated method, are you loading your driver there?

Comment: I removed any parallel configuration and it only ran in one web driver so my config is being used.
Also there are no Before or @BeforeClass methods in my code whatsoever

Comment: @userMod2 it seems you have a different problem and it isn't related to the concurrency what your question asks for. Your question aims to run your test concurrently and the answers here solves that. If you are saying you have no `@Before` or `@BeforeClass`, then I think you are not configuring well your test cases setup. Using both annotation will help you to setup whatever you want (like your drivers you are testing), once you configure that then you can run them concurrently. Unless you are loading every driver individually in each test method you will have an issue

Comment: @userMod2 Therefore, I'd recommend you to create another question with your unit test samples and ask the problem you are facing. Btw, you can let me know I'd be glad to help you out.